# Fetch() returns "TypeError: Network request failed" for specific URL

Tags: javascript, fetch

Code example below returns rather generic `TypeError: Network request failed`, but when I try to visit the URL in Chrome there's no issue. What needs to be modified below? Note: I don't see a similar error with other URLs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const getStandardsTable = () => {
  const url = "https://strengthlevel.com/strength-standards/lat-pulldown";
  console.log(url);
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (html) {
      console.log(html);
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      console.log(doc);
      const table = doc.querySelectorAll(".standards__table")[0];
      return table.innerHTML;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("Failed to fetch page: ", err);
    });
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromApi();
  }

  getDataFromApi = () => {
    console.log(getStandardsTable());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.getDataFromApi}> Click me to fetch </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Edit: This example fetches HTML and produces no error (React native running on Android via Expo):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html')
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((html) => {
        this.setState({ data: html });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Stackoverflow is asking me to provide some more details and I've already provided enough so this is just some text to waste space and make the validation succeed

Comment: What are you trying to fetch? The link is not an API it is just a website.

Comment: Is this in an android or ios app by any chance?

Comment: @TKoL eventually this would be react-native, deployed on Android

Comment: @yudhiesh this is not an API, it's web page indeed. I'm pulling the body HTML

Comment: making a fetch request from another website inside a browser produces a CORS error. As for the error you're getting, `TypeError: Network request failed` from within an Android app -- it's very possible that your Anrdoid app isn't configured to make http requests at all. Try making a fetch request to an api you know should work and see what happens.

Comment: @TKoL added to the question some code which apparently works (just changed the URL to https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html). not clear why the strenghtlevel.com URL is causing a Network request failed

Answer (score 0):

The `API-End point` should return a `JSON`. In your case the url https://strengthlevel.com/strength-standards/lat-pulldown is actually a website not a valid API-EndPoint. Try to hit this url in your Browser URL you will get to know.

Comment: Thank you for responding, however- should fetch not be able to return HTML? I see example such as https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-with-fetch-in-vanilla-js/

Comment: I see :) It  is a valid point from you my friend . Let me go through the resource that you have shared. `I know server-side rendering,` which is a bit different than that you are trying to achieve. because in your case our API-End point is a webhost link itself :-) I am coming back to on this after going through your link !!! And yes Thank you :-)

Comment: @Danny There is also a note posted "Note: this will only work if run at https://gomakethings.com. You’ll get a CORS error if you try to run it anywhere else."

Comment: Error seems to be due to SSL configuration for the domain strengthlevel.com, but it's not clear how to perform so-called "AIA fetching" in react native to get the intermediate certificate client-side

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure because it's not clear how to get more details on the error, but seems the reason for this may be related to SSL certs on the public domain in this URL.

Created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941654/how-to-ignore-ssl-cert-issues-in-fetch-call-when-using-expo) since it's a bit tangential to this one